# Why didn`t it work the imported function in SMSReceived from MainActivity?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Can you tell me please why didn't it work the imported function in SMSReceived from MainActivity.

```
package com.example.smarthome;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MainActivity MainActivityObject=new MainActivity();
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null){
            Toast.makeText(context, "NewSMS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MainActivityObject.AfisareStareLed();
            }
}
}
```

The function from MainActivity is:

```
protected void AfisareStareLed() {
    TextView view = new TextView(this);
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){ 
        if(cursor.getString(2).equals(number) && cursor.getString(8).equals("0")){
            if(cursor.getString(13).endsWith("aprins") || cursor.getString(13).endsWith("stins")){
                TextView textStareLed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStareLed);
                textStareLed.setText(cursor.getString(13));
                break;
            }
        }
      }
      markMessageRead();    
}
```

P.S. I want to make a function which should modify a TextView when I receive an SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of an `Activity` yourself, like you are doing in `onReceive()`:

```
MainActivity MainActivityObject=new MainActivity();
```

Only the Android framework can create an instance of an `Activity` correctly, as it needs to have the `Context` set up properly and the Android framework does this.

In your `Activity` you can create an instance of your `BroadcastReceiver` (you can use an inner class of your `Activity`) and register that using `registerReceiver()`. Then, in `onReceive()` you will have access to methods of the `Activity` and you can call one to update the UI.

Comment: Now i have another problem... When i received a SMS my function doesn`t load it, it loads the previous one.

Comment: private final BroadcastReceiver SMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {                           

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     if (bundle != null){
      AfisareStareLed();
     }
    }
   };
   
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
         unregisterReceiver(SMSReceiver);
     }

Comment: I tried to use a delay before reading sms...but nothing...:| i don`t know what can i do:|

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your comment. You mean that when you read the SMS database you don't get the newest SMS, you get the previously received SMS. Instead of reading from the SMS database, you can just use the SMS content that you get in the broadcast Intent. I assume that you have registered a listener for `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION`. in `onReceive()` you can call `getMessagesFromIntent()` to get the received message. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.Intents.html#getMessagesFromIntent%28android.content.Intent%29